# I have to shuffle SQL Server records using some criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with StudentIds ordered by row number, I want to update `NewDummyNumber` column with the values that are calculated by some logic.

This is my original table:

```
|StudentId|RegNumber|RowNum|NewDummyNo|
+---------+---------+------+----------+
|282840   |15005    |1     |NULL      |
|282841   |15006    |2     |NULL      |
|282877   |15040    |3     |NULL      |
|282878   |15041    |4     |NULL      |
|282879   |15042    |5     |NULL      |
|282880   |15043    |6     |NULL      |
|282881   |15044    |7     |NULL      |
|282882   |15045    |8     |NULL      |
|282837   |15002    |9     |NULL      |
|282838   |15003    |10    |NULL      |
---------------------------------------
```

The logic for `NewDummyColumn` is:

if SkipNumber = 2 then the records will be shuffle like 1st record as it is with dummy number as 1001 then two records are skip for now and 4th record newdummy number will be 1002 and so on up to 10 then this cycle will continue. The result should be like

-- for first Cycle

```
|StudentId|RegNumber|RowNum|NewDummyNo|
+---------+---------+------+----------+
|282840   |15005    |1     |1001      |  
|282841   |15006    |2     |NULL      |
|282877   |15040    |3     |NULL      |
|282878   |15041    |4     |1002      |
|282879   |15042    |5     |NULL      |
|282880   |15043    |6     |NULL      |
|282881   |15044    |7     |1003      |
|282882   |15045    |8     |NULL      |
|282837   |15002    |9     |NULL      |
|282838   |15003    |10    |1004      |
---------------------------------------
```

For the second cycle:

```
|StudentId|RegNumber|RowNum|NewDummyNo|
+---------+---------+------+----------+
|282840   |15005    |1     |1001      |  
|282841   |15006    |2     |NULL      |
|282877   |15040    |3     |1005      |
|282878   |15041    |4     |1002      |
|282879   |15042    |5     |NULL      |
|282880   |15043    |6     |1006      |
|282881   |15044    |7     |1003      |
|282882   |15045    |8     |NULL      |
|282837   |15002    |9     |1007      |
|282838   |15003    |10    |1004      |
---------------------------------------
```

For the third cycle

```
|StudentId|RegNumber|RowNum|NewDummyNo|
---------------------------------------
|282840   |15005    |1     |1001      |  
|282841   |15006    |2     |1008      |
|282877   |15040    |3     |1005      |
|282878   |15041    |4     |1002      |
|282879   |15042    |5     |1009      |
|282880   |15043    |6     |1006      |
|282881   |15044    |7     |1003      |
|282882   |15045    |8     |1010      |
|282837   |15002    |9     |1007      |
|282838   |15003    |10    |1004      |
---------------------------------------
```

Now NewDummyNo colunm not contain any NULL Values so this is the final result.

Please suggest how to achieve this - my #table is:

```
create table #DUMMYNUMBER 
(
     StudentId int,
     OrderStudentRegNumber int,
     RwNumber int,
     NewDummyNumber int
)

insert into #DUMMYNUMBER(StudentId, OrderStudentRegNumber, RwNumber) 
values 
    (282840, 15005, 1),
    (282841, 15006, 2),
    (282877, 15040, 3),
    (282878, 15041, 4),
    (282879, 15042, 5),
    (282880, 15043, 6),
    (282881, 15044, 7),
    (282882, 15045, 8),
    (282837, 15002, 9),
    (282838, 15003, 10)
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Please show your attempt.

Comment: If `SkipNumber = 2`? That column/object isn't defined anywhere in your question, where is that coming from?

Comment: SkipNumber = 2/3/4 is coming from the parameter

Answer (score 0):

If number of records and skipNumber+1 are coprimes, you can do following:

```
DECLARE @skip int = 2;
DECLARE @total int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #DUMMYNUMBER);
DECLARE @skip int = @skipNumber+1;

SELECT TOP(@total) StudentId, OrderStudentRegNumber, RwNumber, 1000+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) NewDummyNo FROM ( 
    SELECT *, R+A*@total N, CASE WHEN (R+A*@total)%@skip=1 THEN 'X' END X FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RwNumber) R
        FROM #DUMMYNUMBER
    ) Num
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (0),(1),(2)) T(A) --number of loops, equal to (skip+1), use tally or recursive generator if needed
) T WHERE X IS NOT NULL
```

If they are not, infinite loop happens.

Comment: Hello @Pawel DyI your query working perfectly for skip = 2 but when I use skip=1 then it is not giving me proper result it is not showing record number 2

Comment: 2 and 10 are not coprimes. Consider 4 records and skip=1. Then you set #1, #3, and then... #1, #3 and then...